# Surge isn't refreshing my new changes to website after pushing

Tags: dns, cloudflare, cname, nameservers, surge.sh

It was working about a month ago and I have no idea what changed.

I am using the Surge along with GoDaddy as my domain provider and Cloudflare as my name server. I have correctly pointed GoDaddy to Cloudflare and my Cloudflare DNS settings has the right pointers from the Surge generated website to my personal domain name website.

After typing

```
surge
```

The command terminal spits:

```
Success! Project is published and running at mydomain.com
```

However, when I go to "mydomain".com, nothing has changed.

Many people have the problem of not having an index.html in their root directory folder where they surge, but I have an index.html file.

Any suggestions/tips/hints? Any would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820150/why-is-surge-not-deploying-to-a-specific-url-but-it-is-to-other-urls) earlier today and it has been brought to my attention that you asked this question 2 ago (April 11). Because of this I decided to check [Surge's Twitter](https://twitter.com/surge_sh?lang=en) and found that the 10th of April they were having some problems with Digital Ocean.

Later today, April 13th, I decided to re-deploy and it has worked. Not sure if it has something to do with Surge's Digital Ocean issue which happened 3 days ago but it's now working.

Just try re-deploying.

Comment: Glad to see that I wasn't the only one experiencing difficulties. Thanks for posting and everything is running smoothly for me now.